# Nested If / Else

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, nested

So I have a sub on a button click that does the following:

1. If the text entry within a combo box (cmbServerInstall.Text) is blank, firstly it will force the user to make a selection before proceeding.
2. Else, a string (strGameServer) is populated with the text within the combo box (cmbServerInstall.Text).
3. From here, a MessageBox will then show with a Yes/No option, asking if the user wishes to proceed.

Here is where things are going wrong.

**What I want to happen**

1. If the user selects yes, then I want to use another if/else to determine what was stored in the string strGameServer. Depending on what this is set to, it will launch one of two batch files (I understand the file paths are the same at the moment, I plan to update this at a later date).
2. If the user selects no, I want it to remove the selection from the combobox cmbServerInstall.

**What is happening as it stands**

1. Basically the shell command launches the batch file REGARDLESS of whether or not MsgBoxResult is Yes or No.

Could anyone kindly take a look at the code below and point me in the direction of where I am going wrong? Nested IFs seem to be getting the better of me.

```
    Dim strGameServer As String

    If cmbServerInstall.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a game server to install", "No game server selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    Else
        strGameServer = cmbServerInstall.Text
        MessageBox.Show("You have chosen" + " " + strGameServer + "." + " " + "Please confirm you wish to proceed with your selection.", "Confirm game server selection", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            If strGameServer = "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" Then
                Shell("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\YorkshaLAN Server Creator\YorkshaLAN Server Setup.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
            Else : strGameServer = "Team Fortress 2"
                Shell("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\YorkshaLAN Server Creator\YorkshaLAN Server Setup.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
            End If
        Else
            cmbServerInstall.Text = ""
        End If

        cmbServerInstall.Text = ""
        cmbServerInstall.Enabled = False
        btnServerGoInstall.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the result from MessageBox.Show and then check it, or do so in one line.

Edit of original code:

```
If cmbServerInstall.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a game server to install", "No game server selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
Else
    Dim strGameServer As String = cmbServerInstall.Text ' Moved init to avoid declaration without use '
    If MessageBox.Show("You have chosen" & " " & strGameServer & "." & " " & "Please confirm you wish to proceed with your selection.",
      "Confirm game server selection",
      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) =MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        If strGameServer = "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" Then
            Shell("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\YorkshaLAN Server Creator\YorkshaLAN Server Setup.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
        Else
            strGameServer = "Team Fortress 2"
            Shell("C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\YorkshaLAN Server Creator\YorkshaLAN Server Setup.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
        End If
    Else
        cmbServerInstall.Text = ""
    End If

    cmbServerInstall.Text = ""
    cmbServerInstall.Enabled = False
    btnServerGoInstall.Enabled = False
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I am very new to VB.NET. I assumed MsgBoxResult.Yes was the value of MsgBoxResult if yes was chosen using the buttons?

Comment: As Steve wrote in his answer it is the Enum for for possible results, the kind of types that `MessageBox.Show` returns. You will always need to use the value from the function in some way, either as using the function in a if as in my example or use `Dim result As MsgBoxResult = MessageBox.Show(...` and then use `If result = ...` I would also strongly sugest `Option strict on` if it is not yet used, also warn on everything and all warnings as errors to avoid learning bad practices. ;)

Comment: Hi mate, Thanks for the update, this has also worked fine, interesting to see that there is more than one way around it. I will have to figure out which one I prefer. Thanks again. Thanks for the warning on 'Option Strict on' does this get declared at the top of the sub?

Comment: option strict on can be set in the top of a file, but I would suggest you to set it in the project configuration instead so it is not missed, the same goes for the other warnings as errors settings. (it is better to do things properly, then to be lazy and be bitten later.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the result of the MessageBox with the question and check the result

```
   Dim result = MessageBox.Show("You have chosen ......")
   If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
       .....
```

Actually your code checks the enum MsgBoxResult.Yes and because it is not zero the if is always evaulated as true

Also, if I were you I would try to remove any usage of the old VB6 syntax and enumerations. Actually [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx) returns a DialogResult enumeration not a MsgBoxResult. This is here just for VB6 compatibility

```
   Dim result = MessageBox.Show("You have chosen ......")
   If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the response. So the Dim will be declared at the top as usual and then I use the If result in my if statement? I assumed MsgBoxResult.Yes was the value of MsgBoxResult if yes was chosen using the buttons?

Comment: [MsgBoxResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxresult.aspx) is an enum  ( a type) and you need to catch the return value from the MessageBox in a variable and then use that variable for your tests (or inline everything in a giant if statement). Of course the readability of your statement will suffer

Comment: Cheers Steve, appreciate the help mate.

Comment: Also try to avoid the use of MsgBoxResult. This enum is just for compatibility with the old VB6 syntax. If you write code for NET then use the DialogResult enumeration